# ssh -vT git@github.com get " No such file or directory" error

Tags: git, github, ssh

[image]

I have alareay add  id_rsa.pub file content into my Github Account Setting.

My OS is Windows10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, make sure to answer yes when asked about the authenticity of GitHub host: you need to have your `%USERPROFILE%\.ssh\known_hosts` updated.

Second, you have re-generated and overwritten your `%USERPROFILE%\.ssh\id_rsa.pub`public key: make sure that new key is indeed registered (as *one* line) in your GitHub profile.

Third, check that you can read that same public key from your bash session:

```
cat /c/Users/lijp/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

Check also your public key fingerprint with the one recorded on GitHub:

```
ssh-keygen -E md5 -lf /c/Users/lijp/.ssh/id_rsa.pu
```

Comment: %USERPROFILE%\.ssh\known_hosts directory only have id_rsa and id_rsa.pub,no known_hosts file .And I am sure new public key has added on github,new ssh fingerprint is shown as one line.And I can see id_rsa.pub's content using cat.

Comment: @张为晓 It will have a `known_hosts` file once you answer '`y`' (`yes`) to the question "`Are you sure you want to continue connnecting?`"

Comment: @张为晓 Can you check the fingerprint of your local public key is the same as the one you see on GitHub? `ssh-keygen -E md5 -lf /c/Users/lijp/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`

Comment: Thank god.After I answer 'y' and 'yes',and run sh-keygen -E md5 -lf /c/Users/lijp/.ssh/id_rsa.pub,I found fingerprint is different from the one on github.and I update the ssh key on github.Now It goes well.